# Different approaches to plugin system

Tags: c++, process, plugin-architecture

Having an application that defines a plugin API, I was wondering how (if possible at all) to achieve both stability and performance (see below for what that means) at the same time.

A plugin in my application is just a processing task, which takes a data structure whose format is defined in the plugin API and transforms it basically. As a rough idea, it could look like this:

```
struct DataObject {
   std::vector<ProcessingResult> processingResults;
   const uint8_t *rawData;
};
```

And a very simplified version of a plugin could look like this:

```
bool pluginMainFunction(DataObject& data)
{
    ProcessingResult newResult("myplugin.name");
    // add to results
    data.processingResults.push_back(newResult);
    return true;
}
```

The first approach that comes to mind is providing the plugin as a .so file and just calling `pluginMainFunction` fromt the application directly. This brings one huge benefit - direct access to the data object. This is especially handy when multiple plugins run sequentially on the same data. No copies at all are needed. And this is what I mean with performance. Our benchmarks have shown that IO in general is the first bottleneck we hit when we serialize `DataObject` to disk and load it again for the plugin.

That said, this is actually the second approach we came up with. Writing very simple wrappers around each plugin makes them standalone executables and we can control them via scripts. The big advantage here is stability. With a little bit of extra efforts we can handle plugin crashes quite well, whereas in the first approach, a SEGAULT in a plugin crashes the whole application.

We are not so much concerned about malicious plugins, but bugs happen all the time and should not lead to a total crash. The plugins themselves can be quite complex actually, somewhat being fullblown applications.

Are there any other approaches that come to mind (maybe keeping the `DataObject`s in a shared memory segment? I would be very interested in reading your experiences and pros and cons you encountered whenever you developed and run similar systems.

Comment: Your question boils down to "which ways of interprocess communication exists for C++ programs", which was [asked and answered in 2008 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372198/best-way-for-interprocess-communication-in-c), and is AFAIK still valid.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the resource. Yes, you are absolutely right that fundamentally, the question is about IPC (but there is no tag for it here). However, it is still an open question weather the usage of a new process per plugin is a good way to go. So I'd like to keep the question open.

Comment: If you want a plugin not to be able to crash your main application, using separate processes is not a "good" or "bad" way (whatever that means) , it is AFAIK **the only** (reasonable) **way**.

Comment: Using a separate process is basically the way to go. If you absolutely want there to be no secondary process, instead consider a scripting engine, or other virtualisation/sandboxing technique. Yes this will have some impact on speed, but with a JIT, or mostly precompiled but hypervised binary that can be offset, especially if non-cpu/memory IO is the bottleneck (eg network/hard drives).